# Outputting file contents as binary as AJAX response

Tags: php, ajax, binary, zip

OK the title doesn't give much a way so let me explain my very strange set-up.

Two servers are involved:

- website: remote
- localhost: local machine

The workflow is as follows:

- The site calls localhost via cross-domain AJAX
- In response localhost dynamically creates a ZIP file via PHP's ZipArchive lib
- localhost conveys the raw data that comprises the archive as the AJAX response

The request is made and the archive is made - all good. The archive is openable, all good. What I'm stuck on now is how to convey that archive as the AJAX response, such that it can be "put together again" (à la Humpty Dumpty). When I do this currently (via `file_put_contents()`) it errors on opening, saying it's invalid. Currently I'm just outputting the archive's raw data:

```
echo file_get_contents('path/to/archive.zip');
```

This is fine, but sends garbled characters in the response. I don't know much about encoding and headers, so apologise if this seems obvious.

For the response, should I be looking to convert it to binary, or sending certain headers etc? I tried sending the multipart/form-data header, but no dice. Headers aren't my strong point.

Please note **cURL is not an option** in this scenario, else I'd be laughing.

Comment: The zip archive is made for downloading it ? or displaying it or what ? didn't understood the objective of getting the archive with Ajax

Comment: The objective is irrelevant - it's the situation I find myself having to work with. The idea is the AJAX response from localhost is received by site and then forwarded on, via another POST AJAX request, to a web service on site, to be rebuilt as an archive. Essentially this is all a means of creating then transferring a ZIP file over AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to read the zip file as a binary data with Blob javascript class.

This is a code snippet from Mozilla documentation

```js
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", "/myfile.png", true);
oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
  var blob = new Blob([oReq.response], {type: "application/octet-stream"}); //
  // you have nothing to do with the blob...
  // ...
};

oReq.send();
```

Then send this file (blob) with POST method to your destination

```js
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("POST", url, true);
oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
  // Uploaded.
};

oReq.send(blob); //the blob that you loaded
```

you can read more in the documentation by Mozilla :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data

Comment: Thank you. I'm gonna go dig into this now and see how I get on.

Comment: Yay! All working - though I stumbled a bit as I didn't realise data sent this way must be received via `file_get_contents('php://input')`, so I just learned something. I was looking in `$_POST`. Thanks a lot for your help.